# CMD; youtube-dl: store the output filename as a variable

Tags: cmd.exe, youtube-dl

How to store the output filename and extension as a variable after downloading the movie using youtube-dl and use it later in CMD batch? The following is an example of a command to download a video from YouTube to the current directory where `URL` is the URL of the video.

```
youtube-dl URL
```

Store the output filename in a variable called `my_variable`.

Edit:
To be completely specific I want to download a video with youtube-dl using a simple cmd batch file that will provide a CHOICE command at the end with option to open the output file with MPC-HC.

I need the method of putting into a variable the output of

```
youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" URL
```

so I can use it later for the following line

```
"C:\Program Files\MPC-HC\mpc-hc64.exe" "D:\Downloads\%my_variable%" /play
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give an example of the command you run to download and the corresponding output. What do you want to do with the variables?

Answer (score 10):

The following command downloads a YouTube video and names it with the same title that it has on YouTube, followed by the downloaded video's extension.

```
youtube-dl -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" URL
```

The following command downloads only the video's title and extension and displays the result in the next line after the command.

```
youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" URL
```

The following command in a Windows batch file downloads only the video's title and extension and stores the result in a variable called `my_variable`.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" URL') do @set my_variable=%%a
```

In all three commands you may also use multiple URLs separated by space characters instead of a single URL. You may also use the `--batch-file FILE` option to replace the URL(s) with a list of URLs stored in a batch file (e.g. `FILE`).

If you can't download a YouTube video with youtube-dl it's usually because youtube-dl  isn't updated to the latest version. Upgrade youtube-dl to the latest version in Windows with pip:

```
pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

In macOS upgrade youtube-dl to the latest version with homebrew. Many Linux distributions support snap packages. This allows the user to install the youtube-dl snap package which is automatically updated. To install the youtube-dl snap package run the following command:

```
sudo snap install youtube-dl # to launch youtube-dl run snap run youtube-dl
```

Comment: I edited the question - I need to use this variable later in CMD batch.

Comment: Since you need to use this variable later in a CMD batch, you may have to write a loop in order to copy the data that is stored in $my_variable to somewhere else in case you want to reuse $my_variable for storing new data.

Comment: how would that $my_var working(if it works)?  given that normally from cmd you do `set a=6`, you can't do `a=6` or `$a=6`  from cmd.exe   http://i.imgur.com/i6B5LyZ.png  If that's different with youtube-dl then why is that?  I haven't tested what you wrote, (though I would if you had a 1MB little youtube video conveniently mentioned in your answer to test it with).

Comment: This often does not work. When you do `youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDHtypVwbHQ` (anyone may safely try it, it is a 5 second video), it returns `Appreciate Nature (5 second video).webm`. But when you actually download the file, it creates `Appreciate Nature (5 second video).mkv`. Different extension.

Comment: @Pontiac_CZ I don't know what went wrong on your end, but `youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDHtypVwbHQ` returns `ERROR: vDHtypVwbHQ: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data` for the apt version of youtube-dl, however `snap run youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDHtypVwbHQ` downloads "Appreciate Nature (5 second video).webm" for the up-to-date snap version of youtube-dl. The command in my answer still works properly, but maybe your version of youtube-dl is not up-to-date. Try updating it.

Comment: @Pontiac_CZ I experienced the same issue with youtube-dl (2021.12.17), but it works just fine with yt-dlp (2021.12.01)

Comment: @whatthe There has been a lot of unsubstantiated posts on Ask Ubuntu Q&A lately (this month) about the youtube-dl package been unmaintained (or even dead). The truth is that the youtube-dl apt package in Ubuntu is not always up-to-date with Google's latest code for the YouTube website, however the youtube-dl snap package was last updated 10 days ago and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you, searched for this for more than 1 hour....

Answer (score 2):

The `delims` approach described here didn't yield satisfactory results consistently for me. I struggled to replicate the problem successfully - all I know is that *some* file names were failing. Consequently, I devised **an alternative solution using `--exec` and temporary file** (or clipboard - see bottom of answer), which, in my opinion, is a bit more elegant, and the concept is applicable to other systems as well. **I tested it with yt-dlp on Windows 10**, but the original youtube-dl will work too.

### Objective pros over `delims`

1. independent of potential output structure changes
2. supports Unicode characters
3. the basic idea works on other operating systems
4. generally more reliable

### The code

```
setlocal
chcp 65001>nul
youtube-dlp --exec "echo {}>%TEMP%\ytName" https://example.com/video_page
set /p name=<%TEMP%\ytName
del %TEMP%\ytName

rem optional part (example of use) START
choice /c yn /m "Do you wish to open downloaded file (Yes/No)?"
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 start "" %name%
rem optional part (example of use) END
endlocal
```

### Detailed explanation

1. sets local variable scope, so we won't pollute global namespace
2. set code page to Unicode (code page 65001), so Unicode characters will be properly saved and redirect command output to `NUL` (because it always confirms with "code page changed to..." stdout message)
3. run `youtube-dl` (or `yt-dlp`) and write output file name to temporary file (`%TEMP%\ytName`) - `{}` in `--exec` works as placeholder for output file name. Of course you can use your own parameters, including changing output template or even **more `--exec` parameters**.
4. set variable `name` to the contents of the temporary file (i.e. output file name; it's **quoted already** if path contains spaces)
5. delete temporary file
6. [optional part/example] Asks user if one want to asynchronously run file in default application with yes/no choice. Take note it's `start ""`**`%name%`**, not `start ""`**`"%name%"`** - no quotes
7. end local scope for variables - from now `%name%` won't be available anymore

### Notes

1. I didn't use `set name={}` because it seems that exec creates own `cmd` session, so variables aren't available after execution
2. if you run it from command line (i.e. not as a batch script that ends session when it finishes), you *might* want some solution to get back to original code page, because chcp changes it for current `cmd` session, not just for script. Like here: [changing to codepage 65001 and reverting to the before chosen codepage](https://superuser.com/a/1523968/519232)

### Alternative version - use clipboard instead temporary file

In the command use `--exec "echo {} | clip"`; two subsequent lines won't be needed anymore, same as `setlocal`/`endlocal`. Remember that `echo X` really prints `X[EOL]`, so you may want to trim it. Also there's no way to set variable value to clipboard content in `cmd` (you can do that only in PowerShell as far as I'm concerned) without 3rd party, so it's not really useful except when the goal is to have it copied to clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set "YLink=PASTE_LINK_HERE"

"%~dp0youtube-dl.exe" --get-filename %YLink%>%tmp%\LnkNE.txt
"%~dp0youtube-dl.exe" -e --get-title %YLink%>%tmp%\LnkNO.txt
"%~dp0youtube-dl.exe" --get-description %YLink%>%tmp%\LnkD.txt

:: Set /p Below copies First Line Only
Set /p NameOnly=<%tmp%\LnkNO.txt
Set /p NameExt=<%tmp%\LnkNE.txt
Set /p DescOnly=<%tmp%\LnkD.txt

echo NameOnly: %NameOnly%
timeout 2 >nul
echo NameExt: %NameExt%
timeout 2 >nul
echo DescOnly:
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%Tmp%\LnkD.txt") do (echo %%A)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment 'karel' now, so for Windows with youtube-dl.exe in some folder:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%~d0"%~p0"youtube-dl.exe --get-filename -o "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/watch^?v^=O1abcdefgh') do set my_variable=%%a
```

Windows. Download video and audio in the best quality to your desktop with the original name with the url taken from the clipboard.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%I in (powershell.exe) do if "%%~$PATH:I" neq "" (
    set getclip=powershell "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;$tb=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox;$tb.Multiline=$true;$tb.Paste();$tb.Text"
)
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%getclip% ^| findstr /n "^"') do (
    set "line=%%I" & set "line=!line:*:=!"
)
set "psCommand="[Environment]::GetFolderPath('DesktopDirectory')""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "Desktop=%%I"
%~d0"%~p0"youtube-dl.exe -f "bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]" -o "!Desktop!\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" !line!
```