# changing to codepage 65001 and reverting to the before chosen codepage

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've got a C++-program that produces a batch-file to undo the changes it made. The batch-file uses "`CHCP 65001`" at the beginning. Is there any way to store the before chosen codepage before that and to revert to this codepage at the end of the batch?

Comment: `chcp` will display the current code page. Store this in a variable ...

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there any way to store the current codepage and to revert to this later?

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackq tokens=4" %%i in (`chcp`) do (
  set _codepage=%%i
  )
rem do other stuff here
chcp %_codepage%
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Chcp - Change Code Page - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)
- [For /f - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Comment: "usebackq tokens=4" is only guaranteed to work for an English locale.

Comment: @Enno Really? Do some code pages contain spaces? Can you give an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: No, it is just that, for example in German "code page" becomes one word, thus the code page itself the third item. Alas, it is now followed by a dot, say "Aktive Codepage: 850." This [adaption](https://superuser.com/questions/1118106/can-the-utf-8-code-page-identifier-65001-be-different-on-other-computers/1121076#1121076)  `for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%G in ('chcp') do set "_chcp=%%G" && IF "%_chcp:~-1%"=="." set "_chcp=%_chcp:~0,-1%"` seems more robust by using the `:` delimiter.